# Nearby API Package for React Native

Tags: react-native, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections, google-nearby-messages

I was searching for the Nearby API package. I found 2 packages but both the packages are deprecated. Can someone please help me if they are aware of any package that is available in react native for Nearby API? I have tried below package but they are not working correctly and also giving deprecation warning.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nearby-api

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adrianso/react-native-nearby-api

Thanks in advance